# LINQ .Sum() is returning incorrect data

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

My database table has the following:

```
ID   PollID Count
1    6      0    
2    6      1
```

Obviously doing a: `SELECT SUM([COUNT]) WHERE POLLID = 6` would return 1

However, this LINQ code is returning 2.

```
long totalVoteCount = (from pa2 in df.PollAnswers
                       where pa2.Poll.ID == pollID
                      select pa.Count).Sum();
```

While writing this question, I noticed that the above LINQ code is returning incorrect data for other queries.  What exactly am I doing wrong here?  I want to **SUM** the **COUNT** column for a prticular **POLLID**.

Comment: I suppose `select pa.Count` is a typo? Otherwise, if you have a `pa` variable in scope, it would explain your problem.

Comment: wow, that's embarrassing.  Frederic' post that answer and i'll accept it.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831344/linq-sum-is-returning-incorrect-data?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Lambdas make those queries easier to me,            `df.PollAnswers.Where(pa=>pa.PollID == pollID).Sum(pa2=>pa2.Count)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're projecting `pa.Count` from your query instead of `pa2.Count`.

Therefore, if you have a `pa` variable in scope that refers to an object whose `Count` property is `1`, and there are two items in `df.PollAnswers`, your query will indeed always return `2`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of selecting from df.PollAnswers and then doing pa2.Poll.ID you should try selecting directly from Polls collection (or whatever name it has). This way, you probably get some duplicates or your query just doesn't make sense.